# How does Function contain space?

Tags: php

I have little strange behavior.

my div have spaces when i insert a function . forexample :

if i put this

```
   include ('header.php');
   $view->header_login();
   setlanguage();   // <--------this is my language function
```

i get space like that [image]

if i remove that function

```
   include ('header.php');
   $view->header_login();
   //setlanguage();
```

i get this [image]

- Does my function contain spaces ? thanks in advance.

Here is my function

```
function setlanguage(){
   if(!isset($_SESSION['selectlang'])){$_SESSION['selectlang'] = 'English' ;}
   if(!isset($_GET['lang'])){$_GET['lang'] = 'english' ;}
   switch ($_GET['lang']){
   case "english" :
        $_SESSION['selectlang'] = 'English';
      include("lang/english.php");
      break;
   case "swedish" :
        $_SESSION['selectlang'] = 'Swedish';
       include("lang/swedish.php");
       break;
   case "russian":
        $_SESSION['selectlang'] = 'Russian';
       include("lang/russian.php");
     break;
   default :
        include("lang/english.php");
    }

   }
```

EDIT:

english.php

```
 <?php
 define("NEW_GOOD_NAME_CONSTANT", "I have a value");
 define("Free_website", "talking website");
 define("Home", "Home");
 ?>
```

Comment: it is your included files that may contain spaces

Comment: Or the css associated with the inserted html...

Comment: i just included that function , if i remove it its normal.

Comment: is that just how long the element in the browser is?  What happens if you echo strlen?

Comment: Yes perhaps something in the include files.

Comment: Any link to the live page or where we can see the issue? How are you echoing the language? Its probably the CSS or presentation issue.

Comment: show us english.php file

Comment: tip for next time: format you code (perhaps using an online formatter)

Comment: Drop the use of `?>` at the end of your PHP files (there's a q&a explaining why here at SO). Not sure if relevant to your problem, but anyway, just kick it out ;)

Comment: Try removing all `?>` tags (in all files) if there's no HTML beyond that. @echo_Me

Comment: You mention **"div"**. DIVs will do that. If that is the case, you can try replacing `<div id="example">` with `<span id="example">` as an example. @echo_Me

Comment: @Fred-ii- thanks for that , but i think the solution of saving with UTF-8 without BOM as solved me of the anonymous , BTW he deleted his answer :) ,  i would accept him

Comment: Ah, the dreaded "BOM". Am glad you found the solution :) and you're welcome. @echo_Me - If you're able to call the person out, and ask to undelete the answer maybe. Then again, aren't you able to see deleted answers with your rep points?

Comment: @Fred-ii- yes im able to see , but cant do anything to him just call him somewhere :).

Comment: I will definitely remember this one for future reference. @echo_Me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The same thing happened to me.

I found out that it has to do with the method of encoding when using Notepad++.  `UTF-8 without BOM` seemed to work.

However, I found a workaround to it since I preferred `UTF-8` and it should work:

```
<span style="display: none"><?php include ('header.php'); ?></span><?php
$view->header_login();
setlanguage();
```

Comment: yes im using notpad++ with encoding utf8 in swedish and russian files.

Comment: Exactly.  For it to work, you would need to encode in `UTF-8 without BOM` or use the workaround.

Comment: thanks as you guessed exactly that im exactly in your case , but carpet have fixed it without workaround :) +1 for effort.

Comment: If it is for a function, you do not need it to display anything.

Comment: I think there was some confusion.  I thought that you meant that the file that you were including had a function that you were going to call later.

Comment: Thanks for same issue as me :) and it fixed this BOM , i saved without BOM , and bomm it fixed :) .

Comment: Great.  I thought that it was not working for you before since it seemed to not be what I was thinking from your comments.

Comment: in fact i didnt test it in begining , directly tested the other answer, and i didnt see also where to save without BOM, but now i found it and save it and worked :).

Answer (score 3):

In your `english.php`, there spaces after the closing `?>`

```
?>          
  ^^^^^^^^^^
```

You don't need the closing `?>`, so just drop it, the entire file would then look like:

```
 <?php
 define("NEW_GOOD_NAME_CONSTANT", "I have a value");
 define("Free_website", "talking website");
 define("Home", "Home");
```

You may also have an UTF-8 BOM (byte-order-mark) in your files, you can check this on a UNIX/Linux box with:

```
$ head -c3 sleep | hexdump -C
00000000  ef bb bf                                          |...|
```

If your output is similar to this (0xef 0xbb 0xbf), then there's a BOM present. The BOM is interpreted as whitespace by PHP.
On Windows, you'll need to use a HEX editor to check this.

Removing this depends on your editor, you should find a setting "save with BOM", or something to that effect, and disable it. [This page](http://www.sunfinedata.com/tips/remove-bom-from-utf-8-files/) also lists a number of methods to remove a BOM.

Comment: @echo_Me The other answer about the BOM seems to have disappeared, but I've edited my answer to include the same info.

Comment: Thanks for detailed BOM Carpet Really helpfull. but i called him the one who answered it, if he will not undelette his answer then i accept yours.

Comment: @echo_Me Yeah, not sure why he/she removed it, it was a good post, and had a bunch of upvotes (including mine).